# Getting Jetty & Maven to work form TextMate

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, jetty, textmate

I often work in Eclipse, but recently switched to TextMate, which is, in my opinion, the best text editor out there, barring perhaps VIM or something like that (but I find the learning curve too steep to jump into that quite yet).

The disadvantage is I don't really know how to run Maven & Jetty w/out using Eclipse.  The engineers at work here set up Java projects that have POM files, etc.  And it all runs fine in Eclipse, but I thought I heard somewhere that TextMate actually had a bundle somewhere to use Maven with, and I wondered if such a thing might include Jetty too.

I'm a UI guy, so please, keep the technical jargon down just a tad.  (In other words, I don't do Java, though I understand some of it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need anything fancy to run a Mavenized webapp on Jetty. Simply add the following snippet to your `pom.xml` (assuming your project has a packaging of type war as illustrated below):

```
<project>
  ...
  <packaging>war</packaging> <!-- this is the packaging for a webapp -->
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.22</version>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
</project>
```

And just run the following command in a console:

```
mvn jetty:run
```

Just in case, there is a [Maven bundle for TextMate](http://macromates.com/svn/Bundles/trunk/Bundles/Maven.tmbundle) allowing to invoke Maven from TextMate. You can check [this mail](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/200803.mbox/%3CF67101AE-629F-4C87-B923-C531DACFB546@ldaley.com%3E) for details.